# Nested components testing with Enzyme inside of React & Redux

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, redux, enzyme

I have a component `SampleComponent` that mounts another "connected component" (i.e. `container`). When I try to test `SampleComponent` by `mount`ing (since I need the `componentDidMount`), I get the error:

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or
>   props of "Connect(ContainerComponent)". Either wrap the root component
>   in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to
>   "Connect(ContainerComponent)".

What's the best way of testing this?

Comment: Since Enzyme v3, shallow calls ComponentDidMount https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md FYI

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I essentially did was bring in my `redux` store (and `Provider`) and wrapped it in a utility component as follows:

```
export const CustomProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {children}
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

then, I `mount` the `SampleComponent` and run tests against it:

```
it('contains <ChildComponent/> Component', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <CustomProvider>
      <SampleComponent {...defaultProps} />
    </CustomProvider>
  );
  expect(wrapper.find(ChildComponent)).to.have.length(1);
});
```

Comment: I see you are using mount, if I try to replace ``mount`` with ``shallo`` I get an error. do you have encountered that too?

Comment: While this answer works in some cases, it doesn't work when you need to test your component's lifecycle. For example, calling `wrapper.setProps()` will not trigger `componentWillReceiveProps()` on `SampleComponent`.

Answer (score 43):

Enzyme's mount takes optional parameters. The two that are necessary for what you need are

`options.context: (Object [optional]): Context to be passed into the component`

`options.childContextTypes: (Object [optional]): Merged contextTypes for all children of the wrapper`

You would mount `SampleComponent` with an options object like so:

```
const store = { 
  subscribe: () => {},
  dispatch: () => {},
  getState: () => ({ ... whatever state you need to pass in ... })
}
const options = {
  context: { store }, 
  childContextTypes: { store: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired } 
}

const _wrapper = mount(<SampleComponent {...defaultProps} />, options)
```

Now your SampleComponent will pass the context you provided down to the `connected component`.

Comment: This is perfect!  While the accepted answer works most of the time, the downside is that you lose the ability to use the mount api to its fullest capacity.  For example, using the accepted answer of wrapping the component in a `Provider` will not allow one to use the `wrapper.state()` api.  This solution will give you the full range of methods for your wrapper.

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted answer, for the reasons stated above (i.e. your mounted wrapper is not actually the component you are trying to test), and also because then you can use a mock store instead of your actual store, leaving all of redux out of the equation.

Comment: this optional argument is not in docs , how did you find it? in the code ?

Comment: What if `SampleComponent` uses a connected component called `SubComponent`, and we want to check that it renders correctly (integration test, more than unit) using `mount`? You can pass the store as the second parameter to `SampleComponent` but `SubComponent` will have no store.

Answer (score 4):

#### Option 1)

You can wrap the container component with React-Redux's Provider component within your test. So with this approach, you actually reference the store, pass it to the Provider, and compose your component under test inside. The advantage of this approach is you can actually create a custom store for the test. This approach is useful if you want to test the Redux-related portions of your component.

#### Option 2)

Maybe you don't care about testing the Redux-related pieces. If you're merely interested in testing the component's rendering and local state-related behaviors, you can simply add a named export for the unconnected plain version of your component. And just to clarify when you add the "export" keyword to your class basically you are saying that now the class could be imported in 2 ways either with curly braces {} or not. example:

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component{ render(){ ... }}

...

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

**later on your test file:**

```
import MyComponent from 'your-path/MyComponent'; // it needs a store because you use "default export" with connect
import {MyComponent} from 'your-path/MyComponent'; // don't need store because you use "export" on top of your class.
```

I hope helps anyone out there.

Answer (score 4):

There is also the option to use [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/redux-mock-store).

> A mock store for testing Redux async action creators and middleware. The mock store will create an array of dispatched actions which serve as an action log for tests.

The mock store provides the necessary methods on the store object which are required for Redux.
You can specify optional middlewares and your app specific initial state.

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'

const middlewares = []
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares)

const initialState = {}
const store = mockStore(initialState)

const wrapper = mount(<SampleComponent store={store}/>)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use name export to solve this problem:

You should have:

```
class SampleComponent extends React.Component{
...
   render(){
       <div></div>
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SampleComponent)
```

You can add a export before class:

```
export class SampleComponent extends React.Component{
```

and import this component with no redux store:

```
import { SampleComponent } from 'your-path/SampleComponent';
```

With this solution you don't need to import store to your test files.

Answer (score 0):

in an attempt to make the use of decorator syntax more testable I made this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-undecorate

**input:**

```
@anyOldClassDecorator
export class AnyOldClass {
  @anyOldMethodDecorator
  method() {
    console.log('hello');   
  }
}
```

**output:**

```
@anyOldClassDecorator
export class AnyOldClass {
  @anyOldMethodDecorator
  method() {
    console.log('hello');   
  }
}

export class __undecorated__AnyOldClass {
  method() {
    console.log('hello');   
  }
}
```

Hopefully this can provide a solid **Option 3**!