# Testing nested react components with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, redux, enzyme

This is a bit of a followup to [Nested components testing with Enzyme inside of React & Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798741/nested-components-testing-with-enzyme-inside-of-react-redux) ...

I have a component that I need to test props and methods on. However, that component needs to be rendered in a provider in order to work:

```
const renderComponent = (props) => {
    <Provider store={ createStore(reducer, initialState) }>
       <ChildComponent { ...props }/>
    </Provider>
};
```

My question is, how do I test methods on this component now? This does not work:

```
it('can call its own methods', ()=> {
    const wrapper = mount(renderComponent(defaultProps)).find('ChildComponent');
    wrapper.instance().call('someMethod'); // returns Error: ReactWrapper::instance() can only be called on the root
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just google it and I find this link

http://paulsturgess.co.uk/blog/2016/11/06/how-to-write-and-test-a-redux-container-component-for-react/

Don't know if works.. I usually mock the store and don't use Provider...

Comment: You don't need to use Provider. Just add an extra `export` at the end of the component file with only the component (i.e. NOT connected to Redux).

`export default connect(...)(MyComponent);`
`export { MyComponent };` Then import it using `import { MyComponent } from '...';`