# React Jest - Test suite failed to run for PNG files even after adding mockFiles and identity-obj-proxy

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to Unit test my React component which imports another component that contains .png file. Because of this image, my test suits are failing to run.
I tried all the possible solutions with the below configuration, still no luck.

Please suggest, this is my project configuration.

This is my jest.config.json

```
{
    "testRegex": "((\\.|/*.)(spec))\\.js?$"
}
```

My package.json

```
{
    "name": "Application name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "jest": {
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
        }
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.1",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
        "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.18.1",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
        "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
        "jest": "^26.0.1",
        "prettier": "^2.0.5",
        "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.19",
        "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
        "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
        "url-loader": "^4.1.0",
        "webpack": "^4.42.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.10.2",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
        "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "d3-sankey-diagram": "^0.7.3",
        "husky": "^4.2.5",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^16.13.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
        "react-google-charts": "^3.0.15",
        "react-intl": "^4.6.3",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
        "react-router": "^5.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.5"
    }
}
```

My Webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/index.js', '@babel/polyfill'],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 10000,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'assets/images/',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
        // loaders: [{ test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel' }],
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        hot: true,
    },
};
```

My .babelrc file

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Finally my test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import MyPackage from '../Components/index';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Some name', () => {
    it('This should be loaded', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<MyPackage />);
        const x= wrapper.find('#selector').debug();
        expect(x.prop('length')).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

I tried adding mocks/fileMock.js with

```
export default '';
```

and mocks/styleMocks.js

```
module.exports = {};
```

still I see this error -

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    D:\ReactStuff\folder\myproject\src\assets\images\mylogo.png:1
    �PNG


    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

      1 | import React from 'react';
    > 2 | import { HeaderLogo} from '../assets/images/mylogo.png';
        | ^
      3 | 
      4 | const Header = () => {
      5 |     return (
```

What am I missing here. Please suggest

Comment: Unless you specifically run a Webpack build in Jest, Webpack config doesn't affect tests. Jest config does. fileMock.js name isn't magical, it should be specified in config, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#handling-static-assets

Comment: Thanks for responding.

if I get you right, I don't need to make any changes to Webpack.config.js now. I kept it as it is, now modified my package.json to the one as in doc, and updated fileMock.js content to module.exports = 'test-file-stub'; 

Still I see the same error

Comment: If you use jest.config.json, use it and not `jest` in package.json. Did you specify moduleNameMapper in jest.config.json? Make sure it affects tests. Make intentional syntax errors in jest.config.json and fileMock.js and see if Jest fails because of them. If it doesn't, please, provide a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: I added moduleNameMapper in jest.config.json and now I see this error - 

 Could not locate module ../assets/images/mylogo.png mapped as:
    ./src/mocks/fileMock.js.

Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$/": "./src/mocks/fileMock.js"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }

Comment: Update: not really sure, but I overcame this by adding - "identity-obj-proxy", that issue got resolved, however came across this - Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(MyPackage)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>

Comment: Use `<rootDir>` instead of `./` relative path to fileMock and make sure the path is right. As for the error, that's another case. The error means that you use Redux. Likely a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798741/nested-components-testing-with-enzyme-inside-of-react-redux

Comment: Where did you add "identity-obj-proxy" ?